# Posting serialized string to django with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Im trying to make a ajax function to post a list to a django view, but I can't get it right.

My javascript function:

```
    function order_timers(data) {
    console.log(data)
    #Output: timer[]=38&timer[]=39&timer[]=25

    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'reorder_timers' %}',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            #Output: 383925
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError)
        }
    });
};
```

My django view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def reorder_timers(request):

    timerlist = request.POST.getlist('timer[]') #think this is the line that does not work

    i = 1
    for item in timerlist:
        timer = Timer.objects.get(pk=item)
        timer.index = i
        timer.save()
        i = i + 1

    return HttpResponse(timerlist)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you set the data type to `json`? It's not JSON, it's standard form-encoded content.

Comment: Removed type:json, and it seems to post something to the view. But it still seem to be wrong.

Comment: Wrong how? What happens?

Comment: Sorry. Was something wrong in my django code. It is working now. Thank you for your help!